# Problem formatting Bless output

Tags: file-format

I've been trying to output a standard hex dump of a binary file using Bless Hex Editor.

The formatting language provided works fine until I try to get an ASCII column down the right hand side. All I get is `A`s if I use an upper case `A` or blank spaces if I use a lower case `a`.

The pattern I have entered is:

```
[%O% : %E"16"x" "%] | %E"16"t"A"%\n
```

Its the `A` near the end which is the problem - if I change it for an `H` for hex it shows the hex in the right hand column OK, it just doesn't seem to like printing ASCII characters. Has anyone else found this, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I have now found the answer - I am using Okteta instead! This program sends the output to a printer in normal "hex-dump" format. Bless is probably good if you need a spacial file or print format, if you can make it work.